JComponents "Popping Through" Other JPanel
I have been trying to search for similar issues regarding mine, but to no avail.
I have a simple Java Program wherein I have a JLayeredPane with a BorderLayout containing three JPanels. Inside the JLayeredPane, the JPanels are arranged WEST, CENTER, EAST.

When I do any resize on the program window, the whole layout resizes along well at first, but when I contract it till it reaches either EAST or WEST, there's an issue of JComponents popping through the higher JPane layer, like JTextField peeking through the JPanel as you can see here:

So far in my code, there is nothing really sophisticated about how I arranged the layers. I haven't messed around with the JLayeredPane and only added the JPanels and their respective layout positions:
        majorPane.add(centerArea, BorderLayout.CENTER, 0);
        majorPane.add(westArea, BorderLayout.WEST, 1);
        majorPane.add(eastArea, BorderLayout.EAST, 2);

At first, before the issue brought itself up, I wasn't using any JLayeredPane at first and my implementation was just basic BorderLayout and then the layout positions of the JPanels. The problem showed it self when I worked with the CENTER and EAST JPanels on my program, and when I shrunk the program window along the left or right, the JTable (which was in a JScrollPane) rows would "bleed" through the EAST JPanel whenever I clicked on the gaps in the EAST JPanel. The issue seemingly resolved itself when I applied JLayeredPane and placed both JPanels inside it, and this time, the JScrollPane containing the JTable actually resized it self accordingly and didn't bleed through the EAST panel.
However, adding the WEST panel revived the issue again and every time I shrunk the program window to the WEST JPanel side, that's when the buttons and textfields on that JPanel bled through the EAST JPanel. So far, arranging the layer hierarchy of the JPanels did not do anything.
Any diagnosis on why this happen or if there is any other doing it, I would appreciate learning about it. Thank you.
Here is a sample code of how I did it:
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MinimalExample extends JFrame {
    JPanel center, east, west, north, south;
    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JTable table;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JTextField textField;
    JComboBox<String> one, two;
    JButton button;

    String[][] rows = new String[0][0];
    String[] cols = { "Sample", "Sample", "Sample", "Sample", "Sample", "Sample" };

    public MinimalExample() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        north = new JPanel();
        north.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        north.setBackground(Color.red);
        north.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        south = new JPanel();
        south.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        south.setBackground(Color.red);
        south.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        center = new JPanel();
        center.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        center.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        center.setSize(300, 300);

        table = new JTable(rows, cols);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        center.add(scrollPane);
        layeredPane.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER, 0);

        east = new JPanel();
        east.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        east.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        east.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        button = new JButton("Click");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 50));
        east.add(button);
        layeredPane.add(east, BorderLayout.EAST, 1);

        west = new JPanel();
        west.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        west.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        west.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(210, 200));

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 30));

        one = new JComboBox();
        two = new JComboBox();
        one.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 30));
        two.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 30));

        west.add(textField);
        west.add(one);
        west.add(two);

        layeredPane.add(west, BorderLayout.WEST, 2);
        add(layeredPane);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new MinimalExample();
        });
    }
}


Have you considered setting minimum sizes for the [GUI] components?

I think that this has nothing to do with use of a JLayeredPane and all due to use of BorderLayout with components that are unable to shrink.

A side note: best to avoid setting sizes or even preferred sizes but rather letting components size themselves (e.g., setting the font and column properties of text components, setting font of the JButton, calling setPrototypeDisplayValue(...) on the JComboBoxes, and overriding getPreferredSize in a smart fashion where absolutely needed. Then call pack() on the JFrame after adding all components and before making it visible. That does not solve the current problem but will prevent other problems.

MouseEvents are passed to the component under the mouse. In the case of the JComboBox, it would appear the JButton will receive the event, which causes it to be repainted. So, you need to add a MouseMotionListener to the green panel to intercept the MouseEvent so it is not forwarded to the component under the green panel.

You would need a MouseListener to prevent a mousePressed from being passed to the text field if the user clicks in that area.

I have made a few changes in your code to avoid the “appearances”, it can be improved, I hope it serves as a base for you.
public MinimalExample() {
   setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
   setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
   setFocusable( true );
   setSize( 500, 500 );

   north = new JPanel();
   south = new JPanel();
   center = new JPanel();
   east = new JPanel();
   west = new JPanel();
   setPanel( north, Color.red, 0 );
   setPanel( south, Color.red, 0 );
   setPanel( center, Color.PINK, 0 );
   setPanel( east, Color.GREEN, 1 );
   setPanel( west, Color.CYAN, 1 );

   north.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 100 ) );
   south.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 100 ) );

   textField = new JTextField();
   textField.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 130, 30 ) );
   one = new JComboBox();
   two = new JComboBox();
   one.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 130, 30 ) );
   two.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 130, 30 ) );
   button = new JButton( "Click" );
   button.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 80, 50 ) );
   table = new JTable( rows, cols );
   scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );

   east.add( button );
   center.add( scrollPane );
   west.add( textField );
   west.add( one );
   west.add( two );

   add( north, BorderLayout.NORTH );
   add( south, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

   add( east, BorderLayout.EAST );
   add( center, BorderLayout.CENTER );
   add( west, BorderLayout.WEST );
   setVisible( true );
}

private void setPanel( JPanel pan, Color col, int lay ) {
   pan.setBackground( col );
   pan.setMinimumSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );
   pan.setMaximumSize( new Dimension( 250, 250 ) );
   pan.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );
   if( lay == 0 ) {
      pan.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
   }
   else {
      pan.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
   }
}

